# how to deploy sharepoint site into windows azure

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I've created a sharepoint site with local database. Now i want to deploy that sharepoint site into windows azure. How to deploy sharepoint site in windows azure.

Answer (score 0):

It's **not** possible to deploy SharePoint to Azure - SharePoint in the cloud is available through Office 365 - Azure is a whole other set of API, Storage and DB